# CSS different in InternetExplorer and Firefox for jqgrid

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jqgrid

I have a [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) whose column separater in Internet Explorer 8 cannot be seen (white color, since no value is present for that cell), but the same grid shows a nicely in firefox. Does anybody know a fix that can make the grid show column border in IE even though there is no value present?

screen shots for Internet Explorer 8

[image]

screen shots for Firefox 16.0.2

[image]

Comment: Can you add `&nbsp;` as the content for blank cells? If so, I think that should solve it.

Comment: It the problem will not solved by suggestion from MrCode you should provide the demo which reproduce the problem. One can see on the picture that you use icons from your custom CSS. Probably the problem is in the part. You should include additionally exact version of jqGrid, jQuery UI and jQuery which you use.

Comment: @MrCode: So stupid of me.. :) thanks, `&nbsp;` solved the problem

Comment: @Ricky added as an answer with some more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't apply borders to table cells that have no content. An option is to add content to the cell, however the content doesn't have to be visible, so the `&nbsp;` character will suffice. `&nbsp;` is known as the [None breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character, it essentially is a space that will always be presented/rendered, even when used multiple times together (unlike a traditional space character). This fixes the borders and doesn't show anything in the cell to the user.